# How to calculate Compute Budget using solana web3js

Tags: web3.js, compute-budget

I am using solana web3js to interact with a program and send tx. In some of the transactions, it fails due to Compute Units limit. I can increase the Compute Unit to a very high fixed number and make them all pass, but it looks very inefficient for using chain resources.

How can I calculate the exact budget for each tx using solana web3js or any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate the transaction and then use the result to set the compute budget.

Here is an example of how to do that. I dont have a written form of it yet, but there should be a guide soon.

[image]

https://x.com/DoctorBlocks/status/1767228653744607240?s=20